# How to pass string from python being called from perl?

Tags: python, perl

Assuming the perl code is something like this...

```
open(STDOUT, ">$PName") || die "Can't redirect stdout";
$status = system("python Example.py $PName.txt");
```

(That is taken from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/perl-script-call-python-linux-551063/)

What do I have to do in python to be able to pass a string to the perl script?

Would I need to simply return the string? or print to console? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system` command is not useful in Perl for capturing output of a command. You should use backticks to execute a command and write to stdout in the Python script.

```
#-- returns one string
$result = `command arg1 arg2`;

#-- returns a list of strings
@result = `command arg2 arg2`;
```

See the linked source below for more information.

Source: [executing external commands in Perl](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands)

Answer (score 3):

You could just print to console, and in perl use:

```
my $from_py = `python foo.py bar`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [backticks (``` `` ```)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/) as in

```
my $output = `python Example.py $PName.txt`;
print "Backticks:\n", $output;
```

A synonymous approach involves [`qx//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/).

```
my $output = qx/python Example.py $PName.txt/;
print "Backticks:\n", $output;
```

To read each line, open a pipe from the Python subprocess.

```
print "Pipe:\n";
open my $fh, "python Example.py $PName.txt |";
while (<$fh>) {
  print "Perl got: ", $_;
}
close $fh or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

As outlined in the [“Safe Pipe Opens” section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens) of the perlipc documentation, you can bypass the shell by splitting the command into arguments.

```
open my $fh, "-|", "python", "Example.py", "$PName.txt";
```

Output:

```
Backticks:
Python program: Example.py
Argument:       pname-value.txt

Pipe:
Perl got: Python program: Example.py
Perl got: Argument:       pname-value.txt
```